# How to colour each item of the popup menu in flutter?

Tags: flutter, popup, popupmenu

I want to give each container colour.
I tried wrapping it in a container and then assiging the colour, but it's not colouring the whole item container. I tried every possible way but its not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg0WD.png)

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'option1',
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
          title: Text('Delete'),
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuDivider(),
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'option2',
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
          title: Text('Edit'),
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'option3',
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.share),
          title: Text('Share'),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  },
  onSelected: (String value) {
    // Handle the selected option
    switch (value) {
      case 'option1':
        // Perform delete operation
        break;
      case 'option2':
        // Perform edit operation
        break;
      case 'option3':
        // Perform share operation
        break;
    }
  },
)

];
```

Comment: Maybe you want PopupMenuButton, which can be styled as a button?

Comment: For example if I have 3 options or items, then I want to colour the container of each item/option

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your purpose is to wrap the child of each `PopupMenuItem` with a `Container` post which you can setup the `color` property of that `Container`. Something like:

```dart
PopupMenuButton<String>(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'option1',
        child: Container( // <---- Notice this
          color: Colors.red, // Set the color here as per your need
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
            title: Text('Delete'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // Similarly for others...
```

***[DARTPAD DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d00d9c24f3672ebb1ab4aec562c91cd7)***

Comment: You don't need a full Container, just a ColoredBox, which has the advantage that it can be const.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks for that. Please have a look at: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/container-color. So I believe just specifying only the color property in a `Container` would be optimised under the hood to `ColoredBox` by default now. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: And again, it's about const'ing.  ColoredBox has a const constructor, and Container cannot.